# Why are answers with high upvotes appear below the ones with lower votes

Tags: support, questions

I am new to Stackoverflow Meta.

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855908/how-to-overload-functions-in-javascript) question in Stackoverlfow. I know that the accepted answer is shown first (right below the question, as the first answer). Till now, I believed, other answers will be shown after the accepted answer, as per number of upvotes received.

Is it not the case? Because the link which I was going through has many good answers(high upvotes), but are at the bottom of other average answers(few upvotes).

In what order are other answers listed? Is the number of downvotes for each answer too considered while listing other answers?

Comment: How are you sorting the answers?

Comment: You manually changed the sort order, either to newest or active instead of votes.

Comment: Oops,my bad! that never caught my eye. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the filter. It should look like

[image]

for the answers to be arranged in descending order of votes.

If you choose "active" / "oldest", the answers will be sorted accordingly.

Comment: I've was just about to submit a bug because of this. I can't imagine any scenario in which "oldest" should be saved as the default order indefinitely. The order should be reset to 'default' or 'active' after some short time period.